# Aggregating on number of nested objects in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping in elasticsearch.

```
"image": {
    "properties": {
        "comments": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "text": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want todo a nice aggregation where I can see the distribution of comments per image. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please show us an example of a document or how you insert one?